# What is the best way to write a large file to disk in PHP?

Tags: php, file, file-io, fwrite

I have a PHP script that occasionally needs to write large files to disk. Using `file_put_contents()`, if the file is large enough (in this case around 2 MB), the PHP script runs out of memory (PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of ######## bytes exhausted). I know I could just increase the memory limit, but that doesn't seem like a full solution to me--there has to be a better way, right?

**What is the best way to write a large file to disk in PHP?**

Comment: What's the source of the data? Also, most PHP configs should be able to handle 2MB's with no problem. Your memory limit may be way under.

Comment: Where does the file come from? If it exists on disk already, then `copy()` would be most appropriate.

Comment: In this case, I am getting the file from a remote server using curl. So, I have it in a variable.

Comment: Skip curl, use `copy("http://example.com/file", "/tmp/local.txt")`

Comment: @mario: that would be pretty easy, but I am copying multiple files and I like that I can run them simultaneously using curl_multi_* stuff

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need a temporary file in which you put bits of the source file plus what's to be appended:

```
$sp = fopen('source', 'r');
$op = fopen('tempfile', 'w');

while (!feof($sp)) {
   $buffer = fread($sp, 512);  // use a buffer of 512 bytes
   fwrite($op, $buffer);
}

// append new data
fwrite($op, $new_data);    

// close handles
fclose($op);
fclose($sp);

// make temporary file the new source
rename('tempfile', 'source');
```

That way, the whole contents of `source` aren't read into memory. When using cURL, you might omit setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and instead, add an output buffer that writes to a temporary file:

```
function write_temp($buffer) {
     global $handle;
     fwrite($handle, $buffer);
     return '';   // return EMPTY string, so nothing's internally buffered
}

$handle = fopen('tempfile', 'w');
ob_start('write_temp');

$curl_handle = curl_init('http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 512);
curl_exec($curl_handle);

ob_end_clean();
fclose($handle);
```

---

It seems as though I always miss the obvious. As pointed out by Marc, there's `CURLOPT_FILE` to directly write the response to disk.

Comment: Makes sense, but in this case I have retrieved the file from a different server using curl, so it is already in memory.

Comment: @Joe I updated the answer. Another suggestion coming you way.

Comment: for the first solution you may have used [`stream_copy_to_stream`](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream) too ;-)

Comment: @user576875 Nah. Why go easy? :-) Just kidding. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Cool idea using an output buffer, but doesn't the callback get called when the buffer is cleaned or flushed? Won't your code still hold the entire file in memory then?

Comment: No need for the buffering. curl can write directly to a file using `curl_setopt('CURLOPT_FILE', ...)`

Comment: @Marc I updated. Thank you. @Joe By setting `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE` to 512, cURL's internal buffer will be flushed each 512 bytes and read anew. Nothing's buffered, since the output buffer callback returns an empty string.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification. This looks like it would work great!

Answer (score 1):

Writing line by line (or packet by packet in case of binary files) using functions like `fwrite()`

Answer (score 0):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33501157/3197408):

```
    $file   = fopen("file.json", "w");

    $pieces = str_split($content, 1024 * 4);
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        fwrite($file, $piece, strlen($piece));
    }

    fclose($file);
```