# save text file more then 8kb (80 lines) fwrite php

Tags: php, fwrite

I am trying rewrite result.txt file after delete first row, which have total 7000 rows (700 kb) size.

Simply open the file, delete the first line then save again.

But `fwrite` function only save 80 rows (8kb) for me. And remaining rows auto deleted.

```
$outfile= "result.txt";
$o = fopen($outfile,"w");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle,2048);
    fwrite($o,$buffer);
}
fclose($handle);
fclose($o);
rename($outfile, 'result.txt');
```

How to write big file with fwrite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP fwrite() for writting a large string to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500998/php-fwrite-for-writting-a-large-string-to-file)

Comment: @RussJ I try already but its not solved my problem

Comment: Buffer size should be set on `fwrite` invokation as well, however, PHP actually should return a properly terminated string.

Comment: Might there be some limitation on your file system?

Comment: have you tried to replace `"w"` to `"w+"` or `"wa+"` on your `fopen()`?

Comment: @Roshan the strange thing here is that oviously the loop must run 4 times (4*2048 = 8k)

Comment: @Roshan `w+` also not working

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone system is ok

Comment: Have you tried to to write a large file with some fixed string in a loop? You do not show how you open `$handle`. Is it an upload file?

Comment: Try also `filesize('source-file.txt')`, output a counter within the loop an `var_dump(feof($handle))` immediately after the loop. Add the outputs to your question.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone This is the whole code, Where I get first line URL and work with this, And after that I delete the first row URL and rewrite file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by replacing `w` to `c+`

Now code looks like this

```
$outfile= "result.txt";
$o = fopen($outfile,"c+");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle,2048);
    fwrite($o,$buffer);
}
fclose($handle);
fclose($o);
rename($outfile,$file);
```